# conditional_variable does not trigger when using array of std::mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

This application is recursive multi-thread detached one. Each thread regenerate
new bunch of threads before it dies. 
Option 1 (works) however it's a shared resource hence slows the application down.
Option 2 should remove this bottleneck.

**Option 1 works:**

```
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;
std::mutex mu;

// go triggers the thread's function
void go() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck( mu );
    ready = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}

void ThreadFunc ( ...) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck ( mu );
    cv.wait(lck, []{return ready;});
    do something useful
}
```

**Option 2 does NOT trigger the thread:**

```
std::array<std::mutex, DUToutputs*MaxGnodes> arrMutex ;

void go ( long m , long Channel )
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck( arrMutex[m+MaxGnodes*Channel] );
    ready = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}


void ThreadFunc ( ...) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck ( arrMutex[Inst+MaxGnodes*Channel] );
    while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);
    do something useful
}
```

How can I make option #2 work?

Comment: IIRC you should release the mutex before notifying.

Comment: In option 2, there is a _data race_ on `ready`. That means the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: With two different threads on two different mutexes each assumes because they locked their mutex they "own" access to the singular `ready` even though neither actually *does*, right? You have **a** predicate (`ready`). It needs **a** (singular) mutex, which your first example provides and your latter does not.

Comment: @dyp It's a pessimization and hence discouraged, which is what you probably remembered, but it should work.

Comment: Try using `std::atomic<bool> ready` instead of `bool ready`.

Answer (score 2):

The code in *Option 2* contains a so-called *data race* on the variable `ready`, because the read and write operations on this variable are no longer synchronized. The behaviour of programs with *data races* is undefined. You can remove the *data race* by changing `bool ready` to `std::atomic<bool> ready`.

<del>That should already fix the problem in *Option 2*. However, if you use `std::atomic`, you can also make other optimizations:</del>

```
std::atomic<bool> ready{false};

void go(long m, long Channel) {
    // no lock required
    ready = true;
    cv.notify_all();
}

void ThreadFunc( ...) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(arrMutex[Inst+MaxGnodes*Channel]);
    cv.wait(lck, [] { return ready; });
    // do something useful
}
```

Comment: If it's possible for the value of the associated predicate to change while the associated mutex is locked, then it's possible for a thread to miss a notification and sleep forever on a condition variable. The problem interleaving: (1) thread in `ThreadFunc` checks the value of `ready` and sees that it's `false`, (2) thread in `go` sets `ready` to `true` and calls `cv.notify_all()`, (3) the thread in `ThreadFunc` sleeps on `cv`.

Comment: @Casey: You are right. That will most likely cause some kind of _deadlocks_.

Comment: Thanks !! is there a way to avoid the bottleneck (aomic)and use array based solution ? for example array of "ready" and "cv" hence each     thread would have its own locker ... I believe that this would result a faster application

Comment: please note that based on your comments i solved it. my last comment has typos.